# How can I wrap all of the aplication inside of a Middleware in Next JS 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I've been trying to wrap all the application inside of a middleware. As the docs says:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
}
```

What I have been doing was:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!auth).*)'],
};
```

Because If I'm not authenicated, I want first to show the login page to the user. I need to match all the routes inside of the application except for "/auth".

Comment: What's happening with what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your entire script inside a higher-order component.

```
import { config } from "../path/to/config";
import { NextRouter } from "next/router";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Router from "next/router";

function handleRouteChange(router: NextRouter, url: string) {
  if (!url.match(config.matcher)) {
    // do something here, such as redirect to a login page
  }
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
      if (!url.match(config.matcher)) {
        // do something here, such as redirect to a login page
      }
    };

    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

This method is called every time the route changes, and it will check if the current URL matches the patterns in config.matcher.

You can make appropriate changes where you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

i am also working on the nextJS-multi tenant solution/example - using the middleware.ts

My solution to this next-auth problem in the pages directory was to add a _app.tsx file

similar to the following from the example .. i had missed it before:

```
import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import type { Session } from "next-auth";
import { cal, inter } from "@/styles/fonts";
import cx from "classnames";

import "@/styles/globals.css";

import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}: AppProps<{ session: Session }>) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <main className={cx(cal.variable, inter.variable)}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </main>
      <Analytics />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

hope this helps

cheers